# Bricklayer.js: how to use Bricklayer multiple times on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, layout, grid

**UPDATE**
I have added @Alice answser to this code snippet to illustrate why and for what i am using bricklayer.
Bricklayer is only modifying the first `briklayer` but completely ignores the second one, i can understand that since i use `querySelector`.

But even after adding @Alice's answer, the result is still the same.
i have tried `masonry` but it messes up the layout of my cards. so here i am stuck with `bricklayer`

here's the modified version.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('click', '#post-link', function posts(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('underlined');
        $('#project-link').removeClass('underlined');
        $('#post-card').slideDown();
        $('#project-card').slideUp();
      });
      $(document).on('click', '#project-link', function projects(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('underlined');
        $('#post-link').removeClass('underlined');
        $('#post-card').slideUp();
        $('#project-card').slideDown();
      });
    });
    const bricklayers = []
        document.querySelectorAll('.bricklayer').forEach(function (section) {
          bricklayers.push(new Bricklayer(section));
        });
        //console.log(bricklayers)
```

```css
.my-title {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    }

    .underlined {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #project-card {
      display: none;
    }

    .bricklayer-column-sizer {
      width: 25%!important;
    }

    /* @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
      .bricklayer-column-sizer {
        width: 50%!important;
      }
    } */
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bricklayer/0.4.3/bricklayer.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div id='post-project' class="container">
      <div class="my-2">
        <h4 class="text-center my-title">
          <p><a href="" id='post-link' class="underlined">posts</a> | <a href="" id='project-link'>projects</a> </p>
      </div>
      
      <!-- This bricklayer is for posts -->
      <div id="post-card" class="bricklayer">
        <div class="card bricklayer-item mb-3">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/gjWk2VpS/Pay-Pal-Logo.png" class="card-img-top">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card bricklayer-item mb-3">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/gjWk2VpS/Pay-Pal-Logo.png" class="card-img-top">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- this bricklayer is for projects -->
      <div id="project-card" class="bricklayer">
        <div class="card bricklayer-item mb-3">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN4ysXq5/django-logo.jpg" class="card-img-top">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card bricklayer-item mb-3">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN4ysXq5/django-logo.jpg" class="card-img-top">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bricklayer/0.4.3/bricklayer.js"></script>
```

any solution ?

Comment: It's not a great approach to reuse `var bricklayer` *n* number of times. Instead create an array to keep track of all your bricklayer definitions. e.g. `const bricklayers = [];` and `bricklayers.push(new Bricklayer(section))`

Comment: If you could share a Fiddle, then I could amend it to get it working for you.

Comment: same result, but after following your method and adding some output to the console. I have noticed that for the 2nd child  `columnCount: Nan`, the first child return `columnCount: 4`, which is understandable since i have set`.bricklayer-column-sizer{width:25%}`.

Comment: @Alicia i will try.

Comment: okay, well if you give us a Fiddle, we will have something to work with. Can't really help much without the code.

Comment: @Alicia Done !!

Comment: Is there a solution to this to have a bricklayer block on a page multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Just looking through your code, and your approach is very slightly wrong. With bricklayer, you only need 1 parent which acts as a container element, and is denoted by the classname `bricklayer`.

- Can you double check that bricklayer is correctly installed and initialized in you app (since that part is missing from your code snippet)
- Next, define a **single** container element for bricklayer, e.g. `<div class="bricklayer">`
- Add a couple of children to your container ([follow this example](https://github.com/ademilter/bricklayer/wiki/Quick-Start#2-create-a-simple-list))
- Finally call to bricklayer, **only once**.

  e.g. `const bricklayer = new Bricklayer(document.querySelector('.bricklayer'))`

Here is [a working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7t9fzhr0/). For more details, see the [official getting started guide](https://github.com/ademilter/bricklayer/wiki/Quick-Start)

Hope that helps. If you can share a little more of your code, or create a Fiddle, I can amend it to get it working for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have Fixed this problem by switching to `salvattore`. but you are still free to post a fix to my `bricklayer` issue for future users. Thank you :D